# SQL Server 2008 std. and TLS 1.2

Tags: sql-server, windows, tls1.2

I have Windows 2k8 Server R2 Std

with SQL Server 2k8 Std installed.
 All fully patched and updated, even optional patches.

I have installed the patch for TLS 1.2 to work for SQL Server (KB3144113), and the SQL Server service is running fine.  no issues.  So I assume since I disabled TLS 1.0 and 1.1 that it is working fine with TLS 1.2.

Now I am using .NET Framework 4.5.2, so I installed the ADO.NET client rollup (KB3099845)
 Check the registry and it reflects for .NET 4.5.2 version 4.5.52333

But I can no longer use SSMS to connect to the instance that is running on the server.
 I Have verified that the registry keys that are needed are in place for both Client and Server to use TLS 1.2

When I do SELECT @@version on the server I get this:

Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (SP4-OD) (KB3144113) - 10.0.6547.0 (X64)   Feb 22 2016 19:04:50   Copyright (c) 1988-2008 Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1  (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)

I have another DB Server with the same OS and SQL Server installed on it, and it appears to be working fine.

Any ideas why I cannot connect to the SQL Server instance?
 If you go to the KB3135244 page, under "Known Issues"
 I am basically seeing a combination for Issue 1 and Issue 2.
 When I attempt to login to the SQL Server instance using SSMS, I get the error that is in Issue 2.

Things that I tried yesterday:

Uninstalled the two patches. The one for TLS 1.2 and the one for ADO.NET

Everything works fine at this point with TLS 1.0 enabled.  If I disable TLS 1.0 and only enable TLS 1.2, then as expected SQL Server does not start.

Install the TLS 1.2 patch.
 SQL Server will then start, but still SSMS will not connect to the instance.  Which is fine, as that is expected.
 Our ColdFusion web server will connect to the SQL instance fine and pull data fine.

Re-install .NET 4.5.2 and then the ADO.NET patch.
 SQL Server still runs fine, connecting to it is fine from CF.
 But SSMS will not connect to it.

I did a repair on the shared tools using the SQL installer.  Did not work
 Did an uninstall/re-install of the shared tools.  Did not work.

If I start SSMS and select Integration Services, I can connect to it.
 But still not the SQL Server instance.
 If I select Database Engine in SSMS
 And for server name select Browse for more....then select Network Server tab

I can see the SQL servers I have running on a couple other computers....which is SQL 2000
 But it does not see the instance of SQL 2K8 running on the local server.

If I re-enable TLS 1.0 then I can connect.....

And as I stated above I have another server running pretty much the same config and it works fine.
 But not this one.

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

Ok, Got it working.
I installed:
ADO.NET - SqlClient (.NET Framework 3.5/.NET Framework 2.0 SP2) 
and that appears to have corrected the issue.  Not sure why, since I am certain I have 4.5.2 installed.